# vector.push_back increment shared pointer count?

Tags: c++

In the following sample, the `shared_ptr` is a great help automatically freeing memory allocated by `uf8toWide()` (`worker()` has many code paths).

In my tests, `Revisit.push_back()` does not seem to increment the count of the shared pointer, and nothing can be retrieved in `main()`.

Can this be done with smart pointers ? Other means ?

```cpp
vector<char *>fnames;
vector<wchar_t *> Revisit;

int main(){
  
  fill_fnames();
  worker();
  
  // process Revisit
  for(auto fe : Revisit) { 
    // special processing for these
    delete[] fe;
  }
}
void worker(){
  ..
  wchar_t *fn;
  for(auto i=s; i<=fnames.size(); i++){ 
    std::shared_ptr<wchar_t> p( fn = uf8toWide(fnames[i]) );  
                                  // uf8toWide allocates memory
    // process fn
    if(some cases) Revisit.push_back(fn);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
vector<wchar_t *> Revisit;
```

should probably be

```
vector<std::shared_ptr<wchar_t>> Revisit;
```

in order to keep data referenced and prevent its automatic deletion (because `p` disappears right after being created).
Then you would have to use  `Revisit.push_back(p);` (not `fn`).

And in this case

```
  delete[] fe;
```

should be removed because the lifetime is now controlled by `std::shared_ptr<wchar_t>`.